# What is the two-cup device called for blowing compressed air into a hole in concrete thru one cup and vacuuming out the dust thru the other?

Tags: concrete, drill, terminology, dust

Does the device below have name? Trying to shop for one online.

A while ago I saw a video (which I can't find at the moment) showing a two-cup device for extracting dust from a hole drilled in concrete, prior to epoxying rebar or threaded rod in the hole. A small duct connects the two cups. One cup fits over the drilled hole and connects to the compressed air hose, and the other cup is pressed against the face of the concrete adjacent to the drilled hole, and it is connected to a vac hose. The compressed air forces the dust out of the hole, through the duct, and into the second cup, where it's vacuumed out. It is not a drill-accessory shroud used *while drilling*; rather it is used *after the hole has been drilled*.

Comment: Unless it is business use, the cost to buy is probably not worth it for the odd hole.  Some duct tape, small plastic containers, will probably do the job just as well.

Comment: Whenever I drill a hole into concrete, I use a shop vac to suck the dust out. I don't need anything more complicated than that.

Comment: Depending on the anchor (esp. epoxy), manufacturer’s instructions might **specify** compressed air to blow out dust.

Comment: Yes, the epoxy manufacturer does call for clearing the hole twice with a brush and using compressed air to clear the dust afterwards.  Somehow a bit of dust always manages to get in my eye with such processes, even when I'm wearing mask and googles; it has gotten caught in the hair on my head and fallen into my eyes later. The stuff of a *Three Stooges* skit!

Comment: I have a ~2' length of ~1/2" hose that attaches to my blowgun so I can (a) blow out the bottom of the hole properly and (b) have my face well off to the side when the dust flies.